# How can I set custom values to jqgrid Paginator?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a problem, I would like to load a jqgrid with many rows, but its too many information to be a process on the server side, them I like set manually a jqgrid paginator the total rows and page and when a do click in next page go to server and get the next group of rows.

Thank, for you help

Comment: Sorry, but I don't full understand the problem. You wrote "when a do click in next page go to server and get the next group of rows". Is "the next group of rows" the next page? What is different from the default behavior? How many rows is in the dataset which you want to display in the grid (100, 1000, 10000, 1000000, ...)? Which "custom value" you want to set in the "paginator"?

Comment: Hi. the dataset has more 10000 rows, for this reason I would like get 100 rows and if a user click in a next page go to server side and get 100 rows. I don't sure if its a good idea.

Comment: It's the default behavior of jqGrid if you use `datatype: "json"`, `datatype: "jsonp"` or `datatype: "xml"`. The client (jqGrid) send to the URL specified by `url` option the parameters `page`, `rows` and some other (for example `page=1&rows=100`). The server should return the data in the format described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data), where `total` informs about *the total number of pages* (100 rows in the page). If the user click on the next button then new request to the server will be send `page=2&rows=100`